# EF6 With SQLite throws an Exception when Using SqlQuery

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework

I am trying to return selected columns from a table using SqlQuery in EF6 with a SQLite database. I have several different ways to try and get the data, and SqlQuery always throws a 'Index was outside the bounds of the array' exception. It is a simple query using the names of the columns in the query. I have tried it with a SELECT * FROM and I get the same error.
Here is the method:

```
    internal static List<GpsCompassDatagram> GetAllGpsCompassRecsByColumns(string columnsToRetrieve)
    {
        List<GpsCompassDatagram> retData = new List<GpsCompassDatagram>();

        string SqlQuery = $"SELECT {columnsToRetrieve} from GpsCompassDatagrams";

        try
        {
            using (CdSetEntities db = new CdSetEntities())
            {
                retData = db.GpsCompassDatagrams.SqlQuery(SqlQuery).ToList<GpsCompassDatagram>();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            retData = null;
            CLog.logger?.Error(ex);
            throw ex;
        }
        return retData;
    }
```

I have tried ToArray(), same error. I tried without the ToList() and then a foreach to get the records and that fails with the same error.

I would love to do this with LINQ, but I do not know of a way when the columns to return are not known until runtime.

TIA.

Comment: Unrelated, but don't use `throw ex`.  Just use `throw` instead.  `throw ex` kills the stack trace.

Comment: btw the query is open to sql injection

Comment: Post the code of type `GpsCompassDatagram` and the input data. What did the interpolated string look like?

Comment: Can you split `retData = db.GpsCompassDatagrams.SqlQuery(SqlQuery).ToList<GpsCompassDatagram>();` into two lines, to see if the `SqlQuery` fails or the `ToList`?

Comment: @Jonesopolis - ok.

Comment: @Fildor, not sure why the structure of the table should make any difference. I can read the table just fine using a straight ctx.GpsDatagrams.ToList() statement. It is something in the SqlQuery().

Comment: @Okan Karadag, yes it would be if the query was exposed to the outside world. It is not.

Comment: @Fildor If I put the query {SELECT GPSCompassTimestamp,CompassHeading,CompassTimestamp,GPSValid,LatitudeDeg,LatitudeMin,LongitudeDeg,LongitudeMin,GeoidalSeparationValid,GeoidalSeparation from GpsCompassDatagrams} into SqLiteStudio it works fine. It is something wrong with the SqlQuery in EF6